# css, cant click backside after flipped

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a little animation that flips a title and has a few numbers on the back i'd like the user to select from.

The issue I am having is I cannot seem to be click the back after it flips

Here's what I have - http://plnkr.co/edit/zSZSNLcpWIT2FV2PvAfW?p=preview

I am just toggling a css class to flip with a bit of jquery with

```
    $("#flipNow" ).click(function() {
 $(".handleTitle").toggleClass("handleTitleFlip");
});
```

Seem to be stumped by this one. There is a css class for hover and a click listener (via jquery) that I would like to be able to fire.

Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: inspect and check the button id of `#flipNow` is correct or not. After that try putting alert

Comment: @NadeemKhan it's correct, the flip is working just fine, I just cannot click the numbers on the back side...

Comment: OK sure no problem.Enjoy. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're flipping the parent so that – in essence – it's facing the top of the browser.  You can see the content that's then flipped down, but you've flipped the content area in a way that its contents can't be clicked.

This can't be solved without restructuring your HTML.  Here's a solution:

## [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/IGygHj2IvIZqWhsUo2ut?p=preview)

This is the major difference:

```
<div class="handle">
  <h5 class="handleTitle">
    <span>1 Title</span>
    <nav class="handleActions">
      <i class="item">1</i>
      <i class="item">2</i>
      <i class="item">3</i>
      <i class="item">4</i>
    </nav>
  </h5>
  <p id="flipNow">Flip</p>
</div>
```

We consolidated the `span` with the `1` and the word Title in one element.

We added the following CSS in place of the old `.handleTitleFlip` rule.

```
.flip span {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-22px);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-22px);
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-22px);
}
.flip nav {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateY(-22px);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateY(-22px);
  transform: rotateX(0deg) translateY(-22px);
}
```

And then we change the jQuery you're using to apply the `flip` class to the `.handle` container.

```
$("#flipNow" ).click(function() {
  $(".handleTitle").toggleClass("flip");
});
```